# Prove that the zeros of the polynomial $G(x) = n P(x)P''(x) − (n − 1)(P'(x))^2$ are all complex.

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

The zeros of the $n$th-degree polynomial $P(x)$ are all real and distinct. Prove that the
zeros of the polynomial $G(x) = n P(x)P''(x) − (n − 1)(P'(x))^2$ are all complex.

$P'(x)$ is the first derivative of $P(x)$

This question cannot be solved by making any substitution. Moreover, trying to take the derivative and substituting is also very messy.
I found the same question listed in a sheet with exercises on the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality.
Is there any common thing?
Do such questions have any graphical representation?
Has anyone found the general format of this question (Prove that the zeros of the polynomial are all complex) applied in any field of science/mathematics?

Comment: Related: [A polynomial inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769366/). There are also off-site links such as https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h58951p359382 (found by [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24G(x)%20%3D%20n%20P(x)P%27%27(x)%20%E2%88%92%20(n%20%E2%88%92%201)(P%27(x))%5E2%24&p=1) )

Comment: You need to specify $n >1$ or it's trivial to find a counterexample

Comment: Do you mean the zeros are all *non-real* complex?

Comment: @Gary Prove that they are not real.
Prove that they are all complex.

Comment: $P$ has real coefficients ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon Nothing is given

Comment: @mathx I just asked because real numbers are also complex numbers.

Comment: @Gary No problem. The doubt was worth mentioning.